# C puzzle: how will you print something on console?

Tags: c, puzzle

```
/*you cannot change anything from here below*/
main()
{
exit(0);
}
/*you cannot change anything from here up*/
```

This was asked during an interview.

I was told to print something on console.

anybody?

Comment: Most likely, the intention is to make the resulting program print something; generating a compiler message will not probably suffice.

Comment: There have been some similar questions just recently involving how-do-I-make-this-basic-syntax-do-something-it's-not-meant-to-do. Has the obfuscated C contest recently died, so a load of judges are now seeking alternative employment?

Comment: The absurdity of the _interview_ questions on here never ceases to amaze me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One implementation defined way would be to use the `pragma` directives to print during compilation.

```
#pragma message "Compiling " __FILE__ "..."
```

Or, you could do this with some macros and a printf (but not without introducing UB in some aspect or the other) at runtime.

```
#define exit(x) printf("Hello, world!")
int main() {
 exit(0); 
 return 0; /* if pre-C99 */
}
```

Comment: because "it works on my compiler" doesn't necessarily mean "it works"?

Comment: @Steve314: I think I made it clear that there is no conforming way of doing it (note the part about UB).

Answer (score 20):

Really surprised that nobody posted this yet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if 0

/*you cannot change anything from here below*/
main()
{
exit(0);
}
/*you cannot change anything from here up*/

#endif

int main()
{
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

Prints at runtime and no undefined behavior whatsoever.

Answer (score 19):

weird question...

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
#define main int lol
/*you cannot change anything from here below*/
main()
{
exit(0);
}
/*you cannot change anything from here up*/
```

Comment: Not that it's relevant, but I don't see how that proves the competence of the applicant.

Comment: Maybe successful applicants will be required to use this technique in production

Comment: Maybe it tests if the applicant is able to do printf-debugging without touching the code? If he is aware of the possibilities of the preprocessor? Or whatever else. Though a competent applicant not being aware about this could learn it within a few hours, even when he hasn't an immediate answer...

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define exit(c) return puts("foobar"),0
```

over main

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma message("Some foobar")

#error This is an error message

int main()

{

exit(0);

}
```

I think the interviewer wanted to know if you're aware of the #error directive ... just my 2 cents.

Comment: the message will appear in the compiler, not the console.

Comment: @tenfour in the compiler's output console

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find a workaround to edit that file, then use a different c file.

Comment: nah..he got pissed when I said that

Comment: hahaha he got pissed at you for giving valid solutions to his ridiculous interview question :P this must have been a fun interview. let us know if you get / accept the job :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, the question asks "print something to the console" - the simplest way to do that would be "echo something". Don't write code if you've already got the right tool compiled and installed on millions of machines.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers involve the #define c-preprocessor instruction to change what the program means. Most compilers also support something like

```
#pragma startup foo()
```

details depend on the compiler vendor. You can make code run BEFORE main(*) is called that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define exit(x) (printf("Bye"))
int main(int argc,char* argv)
{
    exit(0);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1.**

This works without any preprocessor directives in cl and gcc, although I've not tested to make sure I'm not using any extensions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static void exit() {
   printf("Hello world");
}
/*you cannot change anything from here below*/
main()
{
exit(0);
}
/*you cannot change anything from here up*/
```

I think it's valid but I can't remember if masking a standard library function is allowed or not.

**Solution 2**

As several other answers have specified, you can use preprocessor directives, eg:

- `#define` main or exit to be something that calls ifdef
- use `#if 0` to prevent the existing code being compiled
- using `#pragma message` or `#error` to print a message at compile time
- using `#pragma startup` to use a different function as main or to run start-up code before main.

**Solution 3**

If your compiler supports any C++ features in addition to C, there are many answers:

- Declare a class with a constructor and a static variable of that type
- Put the existing "main" function into a separate namespace (or class definition) and write a different global main

**Solution 4**

I also looked for any way of forcing a run-time error (stack overflow, out of memory, null dereference, tc), which would normally cause the program to print something, but couldn't find any way that didn't involve running extra code, in which case the extra code might as well be printf.

Answer (score 0):

If you interpreted the question to mean you could not or were not allowed to edit the file by commenting out `/* */` or using `#ifdef _COMMENT_ME_OUT__ #endif` respectively above and below the section you are not allowed to edit and then introducing a new main, then you should give an answer of using another .c file.